# Evaluating quadratic residue $(6/p) $

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, prime-numbers, quadratic-residues, quadratic-reciprocity

Evaluating quadratic residue $(6/p) $ I want to find for which numbers mod 6 this residue is equal to 1 and for which it's equal to -1. I've tried splitting it into $(3/p)(2/p)$ and expressing it as
 $(-1)^{(5 (p-1))/4} (p/6) $ both methods haven't led to me finding a solution. Is there an easier way?

Comment: First of all, the value of $(6|p)$ is *not* about numbers "mod $6$" being squares or not. It's about $6 \bmod p$ being a square or not. Secondly, there is no such thing as a symbol $(p|6)$ where the denominator is an even number. (Strictly speaking one can extend the Legendre symbol to what is called the Kronecker symbol allowing even denominators, but that is beyond the level you are at when you are having trouble dealing with $(6|p)$.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every prime $p\geq 7$ we know that:
$$\left(\frac{-3}{p}\right)=1 \Longleftrightarrow p\equiv 1\pmod{3} $$
$$\left(\frac{-2}{p}\right)=1 \Longleftrightarrow p\equiv 1,3\pmod{8} $$
hence for every prime $p\geq 7$ we have:
$$\left(\frac{6}{p}\right)=1 \Longleftrightarrow p\equiv \pm 1,\pm 5\pmod{24}. $$

Answer (score 1):

I would simply go with your first method; the second is problematic as $6$ is not prime.

For  $\left( \frac{2}{p} \right)$ use the second supplement law of quadratic reciprocity, to get it is $1$ for $\pm 1 \mod 8$.

For $\left( \frac{3}{p} \right)$ you can use quadratic reciprocity to reduce to $ (-1)^{(p-1)/2}\left( \frac{p}{3} \right)$.

Since $1$ is a quadratic residue $\mod 3$ while $2$ is not.

You get $\left( \frac{p}{3} \right) =1$ for $p \equiv 1 \mod 3$ and $-1$ otherwise.

Now, note that $(-1)^{(p-1)/2}$ is even for $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$. So, $\left( \frac{3}{p} \right)$ is $1$ for $ p \equiv 1 \pmod{12}$ (as $1 \times 1$) and $ p \equiv 11 \pmod{12}$ as $(-1)(-1)$ and $-1$ for $ p$ congruent to  $5,7 \pmod{12}$.

Now, combine the two and get a condition modulo $24$.